# Dynamic Programming [Python]: How to sum each component from an array matrix by loop?

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, dynamic-programming

I would like to have some help, please. So, the idea of this problem is based on dynamic programming; **find the maximum points possible (220 points) from the combination: All 6 battalions should be allocated to 4 locations, and the expected output is: return all number of the combination possible (i.e 2-1-0-3; because [50+50+40+80 = 220]).** *Below is the data table*.

Visualization of the Example described above :

[image: (here)]

And now, at first, **I thought** this algorithm would work:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array([[30, 40, 40, 40],
                 [40, 50, 50, 50],
                 [50, 60, 60, 60],
                 [60, 60, 70, 80],
                 [70, 60, 80, 90],
                 [70, 60, 80, 90],
                 [70, 60, 80, 90]] )

loc1, loc2, loc3, loc4 = data[:, 0], data[:, 1], data[:, 2],  data[:, 3]
bat1, bat2, bat3, bat4, bat5, bat6 = data[0, :], data[1, :], data[2, :], data[3, :], data[4, :], data[5, :]
calc, res = 0, []
for a in range(len(loc1)):
    for b in range(len(loc2)):
        for c in range(len(loc3)):
            for d in range(len(loc4)):
                calc = loc1[a] + loc2[b] + loc3[c] + loc4[d]
                if calc == 220:
                    res.append(str(calc))
                d += 1
            c += 1
        b += 1
    a += 1
print(res)
```

But the output is not what I wanted, and I am **still confused about how to return the number of battalions used for the calculations** (as described above; 2-1-0-3 which results: 220 points)

Please help, any suggestions would be appreciated. **Thank you.**

*sorry for the bad English, though. Feel free to ask your questions below*

Answer (score 0):

This problem is called an [unbalanced assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem).

You can solve it easily with [`scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment.html)

For the first 4 rows:

```
from scipy.optimize import linear_sum_assignment
rows, cols = linear_sum_assignment(data[:4], maximize=True)
# (array([0, 1, 2, 3]), array([1, 2, 0, 3]))

sum(data[rows, cols])
# 220
```

But you can do better on the whole array:

```
rows, cols = linear_sum_assignment(data, maximize=True)
# (array([2, 4, 5, 6]), array([1, 0, 2, 3]))

sum(data[rows, cols])
# 300
```

There are several algorithms to solve this, you can read more on the provided link. Efficient algorithms will involved [linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming).

Comment: Hello. Thank you for the answer. I'll try right away. If you had more clues or explanations, feel free to write them here.